# How to get multiple shipping address subtotal?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address

How to get multiple shipping address subtotal cart item wise? I mean get subtotal of item with different address selected. I'm using Ship to multiple
address option and i want to use that subtotal in `/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php` file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php` file there are function called `setRequest()` where we can get subtotal of multiple shipping each item using `$request->getPackageValue()`. If we want to get subtotal in different function for ex `_parseCgiResponse()` then call `$this->_request->getPackageValue()` method. Hope it helps someone. Thanks.